# WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: qgis, python

I am reading images (through Python) and do something. These images are placed in a temporary file, through:

```
tf = tempfile.mkdtemp(filename)
```

I use gdal to read the images (short part of code):

```
...
tif_image = gdal.Open(str(out_ROI))
x = tif_image.RasterXSize
y = tif_image.RasterYSize
geo = tif_image.GetGeoTransform()
band = tif_image.GetRasterBand(1)
Values = band.ReadAsArray(0,0,x,y)
...
```

In the end I want to delete the folder created with mkdtemp, through:

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree(tf)
```

Before that I close the images just as I read in this posts:

```
band = None
Values = None
tif_image = None
```

But I always get the error:

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

What I am missing?

Comment: Any solution so far ? I'm in the same place

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to remove the folder which is your current system path? I mean, it could be that you are trying to remove a folder when the system is in that folder. Try os.getcwd() to see if so. If it's you'd only need to change the system path (os.chdir()).

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing the variable, you are not closing the file.  To close the file, you need to have:

```
tif_image.close()
```